# B2C claims resolvers in ap.error content definition

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to customize the ContentDefinition for api.error with a  dynamic LoadUri that uses the language claims resolver as well as a custom query parameter to control the application branding.  If I hard code these two values in the string it works.  If I use the claims resolver syntax of {OAUTH-KV:branding} and {Culture:RFC5646} the page load fails and the URL it is trying to load shows the replacement elements before they are replaced.

https://b2cstorage-cdnendpoint-dev.azureedge.net/b2ccardsdev%7BOAUTH-KV:branding%7D/%7BCulture:RFC5646%7D/exception.html

Is this a defect in the api.error content definition or is it simply not possible to use claims resolvers in the exception process?

Randy

Answer (score 0):

Claims resolvers only work in specific Technical Profiles, those being REST API and SelfAsserted (combined sign up and sign in content definition at the orchestrations step). It explicitly only works in the examples provided in the document and the way to pass the query parameter for {OAUTH-KV:branding}is e.g. &Branding=bob@contoso.com